# Signed-ranking numpy array elements

Tags: python, numpy

For a programming project I'm trying to implement the trim and fill method for quantifying bias in meta-analyses. One of the steps in the algorithm is ranking the absolute values of the vector's elements without losing their sign, e.g. what I need is something like this:

```
a_before = np.array([1, 3, -3, -2, 5, 2.5, 6])
a_after = np.array([1, 4, -5, 2, 6, 3, 7])
```

What I managed until now is obtaining the array with the absolute values using `numpy.absolute` and then ranking the values using `.argsort`. What I can't figure out is how I can retrieve the signs of the originally negative values for the new ranked array. Here's a screenshot for further illustration.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
# use bigger numbers so that it's obvious that 'rank' 
# is distinct from the numerical values.
a = np.array([10, 30, -31, -20, 50, 25, 60])
isort = np.argsort(np.abs(a))
rank = np.argsort(isort)+1
signed_rank = rank * np.sign(a)

print(signed_rank)
```

Output:

```
[ 1  4 -5 -2  6  3  7]
```

But I think there is a minus sign missing (`-2`) in your proposed `a_after: [1, 4, -5, 2, 6, 3, 7]`; there is only one negative value whereas the input had two negative values.

Comment: Exactly! I ended up figuring it out yesterday and I did like this except that I didn't of the np.sign function so I transformed the original "a" array to an array of signed ones like this 
`np.where(a>0, 1, a*(1/-a))` and then multiplied it with the ranks of the absolute values. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
a_before = np.array([1, 4, -5, 2, 6, 3, 7])
a_after = a_before[np.argsort(np.abs(a_before))]
```

The output result `a_after` is:

```
array([ 1,  2,  3,  4, -5,  6,  7])
```

Comment: Thank you the answer! I'm afraid I don't quite understand it. You a_before is different from mine but in the case of this one I would need the results to look like this:
`array([ 1,  4,  -5,  2, 6,  3,  7])`

Comment: But since your original list consists of consecutive integers it's not ideal for illustration of what I need. :)

Comment: I don't understand what you need ....   "ranking the absolute values of the vector's elements without losing their sign" that what I answer

Comment: Yes, I'm struggling to explain what I need to do. I attached a screenshot. Essentially I need to rank the absolute values and then add the negative sign to the ranks of the values that were originally negative.